# Object loosing data when passed into anonymous function with use keyword

Tags: php, smarty, slim

Run into a strange problem today. It seems that a object looses it's previously assign data values when passed to an anonymous function with the `use` keyword.

i have a flash message handler that looks as follows. **note** i have removed smarty configuration lines to make the sample cleaner.

```
$smarty = new Smarty();

$error = getErrorMessage();
$smarty->assign('error', $error);

$success = getSuccessMessage();
$smarty->assign('success', $success);
```

the above assignment is done in the global scope and right after the assignment if i execute the following code.

```
$error = $smarty->getTemplateVars('error');
echo $error; //displays the proper value
```

i can see the value is properly set. but when the application reached slim action for the value seems to be lost.

```
$app->get("/password", function () use ($app, $smarty) {
    $error = $smarty->getTemplateVars('error');
    echo $error; //displays empty string
    $smarty->display('password.tpl');
});
```

due to this problem the value assigned at the global scope never reach the template. doing {debug} inside the template shows the variable value is empty. However it shows there is a variable named `error` and `success` with an empty value.

anyone have an idea why this could be?

**UPDATE**

after adding the following code block to flash message retrieval function. I can see that this function is called for a 2nd time once the original flash message value is retrieved.

```
function getSessionMessage($key)
{
    $msg = "";
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Access" . microtime() . $key);
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        $msg = $_SESSION[$key];
        syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Access" . microtime() . $msg);
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

but why would it be called twice? my script only runs once and there is no incorrect URLs that would cause to trigger another slim execution cycle.

**UPDATE 2**

further diagnoses shows that flash-retrieval function is called twice. However apache access logs only show one request coming from the browser.

```
Jun 15 13:35:14 beast apache2: Access0.68291800 1402814114 NEW successGET
Jun 15 13:35:14 beast apache2: Access0.68419200 1402814114 NEW successGET

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2014:13:35:14 +0700] "GET /cunm/cunm/password HTTP/1.1" 200 1651 "http://localhost/cunm/cunm/password" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"
```

it seems that something is causing the function to be executed twice.

**PROBLEM**

so i finally found the problem, it appears that if you use grouping in slim framework the code inside the group function gets executed even when the URL is not matching.

```
$app->group("/admin", function () use ($app, $smarty) {

     //any code here runs even with the URL is not match "/admin"

     $app->get("/servicearea", function () use ($app, $smarty) {
     }

}
```

Comment: `displays empty string` --- how do you know that code is even run? What if you use `var_dump` instead?

Comment: i know that code runs because the password.tpl is displayed i also tested with some concatenation like `echo "XXX" . $error;`

Comment: So what `var_dump` outputs? `echo` does't allow you to distinguish between `0`, `null` and `""`. In programming you don't guess but base your decisions on the **facts**.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) may help as well.

Comment: @zerkms does it matter if its 0, null or "" in this case because the problem is the value set to `$smarty` instance at global scope is not retained when it reach the specific code block.

Comment: error_reporting is set to E_STRICT by default from slim.

Comment: What if you create another object of `stdClass` type, set one of its properties, pass it to the anonymous function? http://3v4l.org/54e2g --- as you can see there is no php version that behaves like what you explained. Which means that you could debug better instead of arguing about how you need to debug (presumably you're not doing it well)

Comment: @zerkms thanks for your evaluation of my debugging skills and assumptions of very obvious problems where i could be creating another  object with the same variable name and passing to a function. Appreciate you have taken your time to do these evaluations.

Comment: @DevZer0: 1. as you can see - my test demonstrates there is no such an issue in php. It was done to demonstrate that the question title makes no sense at all. 2. If you want to find out why it's called twice - stop guessing again: setup xdebug, put a breakpoint into a function and see why exactly it's called twice. That's what a developer is expected to do instead of guessing :-) You see, you spent 55 minutes and still cannot answer the trivial question. This might give you an idea that you're doing something (actually debugging) wrong :-)

Comment: @zerkms i already solved my problem. in-fact i had some old code calling the function twice.I appreciate your suggestions. thanks. i know it gives you great pleasure to put down someone and go on about your high horse. i know you got nothing better to do than sit around SO and rep hunt. I on the other hand do useful stuff everyday. Hope you can trade your reps to some dollars one day.